# Get Databricks Access token using User Selected Managed Identity on an Automation Account

Tags: azure

How do I request access tokens for Managed Identity like I would a Service Principal? Under the hood, Managed Identity is effectively a Service Principal so it should be possible, but I cannot seem to work out the technical details.

For a Service Principal, the following code works:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/v2.0/token \
-d 'client_id=<client-id>' \
-d 'grant_type=2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d%2F.default' \
-d 'client_secret=<client_scret>'
```

When I try to do the same thing for a managed identity, it fails because a managed identity does not have a 'client_secret'. Is there an alternative way to accomplish this for a managed identity?

Comment: For managed identities, you should generate the token programmtically using MSAL. Here's an example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-use-vm-token#get-a-token-using-the-azure-identity-client-library

Comment: Thank you! In using the MSAL library, it specifies that I have a 'redirect URI' configured for the app/client. Are you able to configure a redirect URI for a Managed Identity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results successfully as below:***

> I agree with @*Gaurav*, you can refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-to-use-vm-token#get-a-token-using-the-azure-identity-client-library) to generate Databricks Access token via User Selected Managed Identity.

I created **User Assigned Managed Identity** like below:

[image]

Now, I used the below **code** to generate access token:

```cs
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using System;

string userAssignedClientId = "User";
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ManagedIdentityClientId = userAssignedClientId });
var accessToken = credential.GetToken(new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://azuredatabricks.net" }));

String accessTokenString = accessToken.Token.ToString();
     
var client = new SecretClient(new Uri("https://testkvruk.vault.azure.net/"), credential);
Console.WriteLine(accessTokenString);
```

[image]

When I decoded the token, the **scope** is `https://azuredatabricks.net` successfully like below:

[image]

**Note** that: It is not possible to configure redirect URL in managed identity. Access token is generated without user interaction (server-to-server authentication), it is generated directly by Azure AD.